# Google Cloud hard disk got deleted when I stopped VM. Reason Unknown. All Data Lost

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My google cloud VM hard disk got full. So I tried to increase its size. I have done this before. This time things went differently. I increased the size. But the VM was not picking up the new size. So I stopped VM. Next thing I know, my VM got deleted and recreated, my hard disk returned to previous size with all data lost. It had my database with over 2 months of changes.

I admit I was careless not to backup. But currently my concern is, is there a way to retrieve the data. On Google Cloud, it shows $400 for Gold Plan which includes Tech Support. If I can be certain that they will be able to recover the data, I will am willing to pay. Does anyone know if I pay $400, the google support team will be able to recover the data?

If there are other ways to recover data, kindly let me know.

[resize disk and stop VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfmE1.jpg)

Comment: Contact GCP support and ask their sales team. how are we supposed to know. I know some cloud providers put termination into a queue so it _might_ be possible if you called like 10 minutes ago. But you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I did contact GCP support. They said, you need a Gold plan for support without really telling me if that would help. I understand this is not a technical serverfault question. I just wanted to know if one had any luck with recovering data on GCP.

Comment: Do you have persistent disk snapshots?

Comment: Yes. I took snapshot couple weeks back. Thanks to it, I did not lose everything. But the data is critical. So I am willing to pay if I had assurance of recovery.

Comment: I would, frankly, not expect their team to be able to recover the data.

Comment: ok. What I don't understand is why did GCP deleted my VM and hardisk, when I simply intended to stop and start the VM again. I have done that before. This never happened to me.

Comment: Best bet is you accidentally terminated it. I've done that when sleep-deprived; unfortunately, in this case it's been a painful lesson in keeping backups.

Comment: @ceejayoz At first I thought that too. Then I checked activities. I had stopped VM. not terminated/deleted it. I have attached the activities screenshot. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If the data was deleted, the GCP team will not be able to recover the data. Google does not keep ownership of customers' data and is not responsible for data that is lost.

Google doesn't take automatic backups or snapshots of the instances. The content of the server, the backup strategy, and the security procedures are the responsibility of the customer.

As a design philosophy, Google recommends that customers should build Highly Available / Failure Tolerant / Redundant systems to protect themselves from failures. In the future, it would be preferable, as a best practice, to [perform periodic backups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) in order to avoid issues such as this.

For more information, you might read [this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/designing-a-disaster-recovery-plan) from the public documentation on how to design recovery plans.